# componentDidUpdate() infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I get an error message for componentDidUpdate when I try to set state and I'm not sure why.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if(this.props.isLoadingDept===false &&  this.props.isLoadingEmpStatus===false
  && this.props.isLoadingGroup===false &&  this.props.isLoadingEmpDesig===false){
        this.setState({
    button:false
  })
  console.log('UPDATE')
}
}
```

console log value gets logged only once, when the statement is true, so I'm not sure how and why is it looping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another condition to check whether the button in the state is already false or not to prevent the infinite loop.

```
if(this.props.isLoadingDept===false &&  this.props.isLoadingEmpStatus===false
  && this.props.isLoadingGroup===false &&  this.props.isLoadingEmpDesig===false && this.state.button !== false)
```

Since once you update the state the `componentDidUpdate` will be called and the props you are using in the condition didn't change.